# Unity Ads not showing real ads even though test mode is turned off

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, unityads

I am using the Unity Ads package in my app and I have followed all the required configurations, including turning off the test mode. However, I am still not seeing real ads appear in my app, even though it is already in production.

I have tried searching for solutions online and have not found any that work for me. I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions on how to solve this issue.

Here are some details about my setup:

- Unity Ads version: `3.7.5`
- Unity version: `2020.3.33`
- Platform: Android / iOS

I have tried searching for solutions online (Unity community, the documentation, and various YouTube videos) and have not found any that work for me. Some of the things I tried include:

- Ensuring that I have the latest version of the Unity Ads package.
- Double-checking that I have followed all the required configurations, such as turning off the test mode.
- Making sure that my app is in production and not in development mode.
- Trying different placements and ad formats.
- Checking if there are any errors or warning messages in the console.
- Despite these efforts, I am still not seeing real ads appear in my app. I was expecting to see real ads once I turned off the test mode and my app was in production.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Have you tried forcing Test mode to be disabled from your Unity Dashboard? [A thread on the Unity forums](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-only-showing-test-ads-not-the-real-ads.881554/#:~:text=To%20do%20this%20you%20will,the%20settings%20in%20your%20code.) suggests that this could work and _should_ work without having to do another build.

Comment: Yes ! I already did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you initialise Unity Ads? You could check if it's properly initialised using the `IUnityAdsInitializationListener`, which [this](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/217262566-Why-don-t-I-see-ads-in-my-game) article seems to suggest. If that doesn't work, and the community options didn't help either, I'd suggest shooting Unity support a message, since they can have more insight in your dashboard.

Comment: Yes, I have checked everything and made sure that I have followed all the required configurations. The problem I am facing is that I am still seeing test ads even though my app is in production mode, and I have forced real ads on the dashboard Unity Ads and I turned off test mode in the unity editor.

Do you have any suggestions or recommendations on how I can troubleshoot this issue? I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide.

Comment: Last thing I can come up with is that either your Game ID isn't set properly or that there are no ad campaigns available in your region. Again, if you've tried every solution and you're sure that you're not doing anything wrong, contact Unity support. They can help you better since they have more insight into your situation.